# $C^0$-close of a homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, dynamical-systems

Let $f, g:X\to X$ be homeomorphism. We say that $f$ is $\delta$-close to $g$ if $d(f(x), g(x))<\delta$ for all $x\in X$.

Let $X=\{(x, y): x^2+y^2=1\}\bigcup \{(x, y): (x-2)^2+y^2=1\}$ i.e. $X= \mathbb{S}^1(0, 0)\cup \mathbb{S}^1(2, 0)$. Consider $f:X\to X$ such that $f(p)=p$ if $p\in\{(-1, 0), (1, 0), (3, 0)\}$ and the first coordinate of $f(x, y)$ is larger than
$x$. Indeed the homeomorphism $f$ has three fixed point and if $(x, y)\notin \{(-1, 0), (1, 0), (3, 0)\}$ and $f(x, y)=(a, b)$ then $a>x$.

Let $g:X\to X$ be close enough to $f$. Is it true that $g(\mathbb{S}^1(0, 0))= \mathbb{S}^1(0, 0)$ and $g(\mathbb{S}^1(2, 0))= \mathbb{S}^1(2, 0)$?

Would you please help me to know it.

Comment: What precisely do you mean by "larger than":  $\ge $ or $>$?

Comment: @PaulFrost It means >.

Comment: But what about $f(p) = p$ for the three values in your question?

Comment: @PaulFrost.The homeomorphism $f$ has three fixed point and if $(x, y)\notin \{(-1, 0), (1, 0), (3, 0)\}$ and $f(x, y)=(a, b)$ then $a>x$.

Comment: Okay, you should clarify this in your question. Readers do not want to read comments to get all necessary information.

Comment: @PaulFrost Thanks. I do it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Each homeomorphism $h : X \to X$ keeps $p = (1,0)$ fixed. This is true because $p = (1,0)$ is the only point such that $X \setminus \{p\}$ is not connected.
2. Let $X_0 = S^1(0,0) \setminus \{p\}$ and $X_2 = S^1(2,0) \setminus \{p\}$. These are the components of $X \setminus \{p\}$. Thus each homeomorphism $h : X \to X$ either maps $X_0$ to $X_0$ and $X_2$ to $X_2$ or maps $X_0$ to $X_2$ and $X_2$ to $X_0$. Hence $h$ either maps $S^1(0,0)$ to $S^1(0,0)$ and $S^1(2,0)$ to $S^1(2,0)$ or maps $S^1(0,0)$ to $S^1(2,0)$ and $S^1(2,0)$ to $S^1(0,0)$.
3. Let $f : X \to X$ be a homeomorphism such that $f(-1,0) \in S^1(0,0)$ and let $d(f(-1,0),(1,0)) = r$. Note that $r > 0$ because $f(-1,0) \ne (1,0)$. Then if $d(f(x),g(x)) < r$ we have $g(S^1(0,0)) = S^1(0,0)$ and $g(S^1(2,0)) = S^1(2,0)$. In fact, we have $g(-1,0) \in S^1(0,0)$ since $f(-1,0) \in S^1(0,0)$ and $d(f(-1,0),g(-1,0)) < r$.